# How do I fix two competing symfony routes

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a route that is defined as such:

```
/**
* @Route("/{project_url}/posts/{post_id}", name="project-post-view")
*/
public function projectEditPosts(string $project_url, int $post_id): Response
{...}
```

and

```
/**
* @Route("/{project_url}/posts/new", name="project-new-post")
*/
```

These two routes compete with one another. The first route has post_id that is defined as an int within the controller function, while the other doesn't define anything beyond the first variable.

How do I get these two to not compete? I know it seems silly to just change the route, but from a URL perspective, these make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This was a case of ordering for the controller. Anyone who comes across this issue, make sure to put your static route first, then your dynamic route **after**.

That fixed my issue.

Comment: you can also use priority to alter the loading order https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter